# Invalid Host header in reactjs production

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i config proxy in package.json when i take domain to my production (IPv4). it appear that 'Invalid Host header'. i try to config HOST in .env.development when i start after config , i can't run npm start because it appear below follow that

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND gionie.com:8081 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1499:12)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:17)
```

Comment: when posting error messages, logs and code, please put it inside a code block (4 spaces on the beggining of line)

Comment: Looks like the port number is included in the header value? If so remove it.

Comment: and, is the address `gionie.com:8081` valid? is it accessible from the machine that you are running npm start?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I config proxy to gionie.com:8081 and i don't exact know what should i config HOST in .env.development